# Hat dash records time while the game is paused as time played

Tags: bug, status-completed, winter-bash-2020, hat-dash

I think there is a bug in the recording of how long one played the hat dash game. If I start a game and immediately switch to a different tab page in my browser, the game is automatically paused. If I then wait 5 minutes and go back to the browser tab with the game, it will automatically resume. I then let the unicorn bump into the first object and the game will say I played 5 minutes and a bit. Shouldn't pausing the game also pause the "time played" recording?

**Warning for people trying this out**: this can get you excluded from the overall "Most Time Spent Playing" scoreboard.

Comment: I don't think it's browser dependent. Tried in both Chrome and Edge browsers, got the same result as you https://i.stack.imgur.com/bdbm7.png

Comment: @TheTechExpertGuy it's not for children. It's a copy of mini-game inside Chrome when the internet connection is down. See [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dinosaur_Game) for the full details.

Comment: On macOS, switching to a different app doesn't pause the game, but switching to a different browser tab does.

Comment: Technically, I think the browser itself simply "freeze" any client side code which is currently running. There is a big chance it's not technically possible for the game to identify it's being paused. Solution might be for the game to send "pings" to the server every second, and the server will then record the pings, but alas... that would require too much time.

Comment: Regarding the edit: they most likely perform sanity checks, e.g. they will ignore game with score of less than 1000 that took over 10 minutes, as people can spoof stats by sending directly to the server. Exact numbers are of course not public anywhere.

Comment: The time played is just calculated as end time - starttime as far as I can tell from the JS.

Comment: @Shadow10YearsWizard That was my thought as well, so I tried pausing not longer than 1 or 2 minutes and play a bit when I resume. I now think that the pause time is not counted in today's "most time spent" stat. That went up only a tiny bit for a game, or nor at all. The paused time is included in the overall stat (I have 85.97 minutes with 155 games), but I am apparently excluded from that scoreboard.

Comment: @ShadowtheHatterWizard Yeah, but I think that the Google Dinosaur game is for children, not for adults.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not going to go into implementation details, but this is no longer an issue. Thanks for bringing it to my attention.

> hat dash game is paused
> time no longer recording
> cheating now harder