# Tripped on a speck of dust in Hat Dash

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, winter-bash-2020, hat-dash

I was waiting for my code to compile, but suddenly while playing I died for no apparent reason!

[image]

Comment: Maybe you ran out of water? ;)

Comment: @ShadowtheHatterWizard Unlikely, my computer uses a closed loop water cooling system (as opposed to my previous solution, which was throwing it on a river, but that affected build times negatively)

Comment: Probably a side effect of https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/358222: if you switch a tab or the window loses focus, then you automatically lose the game.

Answer (score 5):

> There was a reason
> for your untimely demise.
> Next time, keep **focus**

Answer (score 4):

In order to fix [Hat dash records time while the game is paused as time played](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/358174/435726), it seems that Yaakov added a `focusCheck()` function, which is called each time the game starts, so as to stop when it loses focus. A comment was added above the  `onVisibilityChange()` function too:

```
/**
 * New: Not going to pause the game, prevent folks messing around
 * Old: Pause the game if the tab is not in focus.
 */
```

The new function:

```
/* End the game if it is playing and loses focus */
focusCheck: function () {
    if (this.nfc) {
        return;
    }
    var self = this;
    var t = function () {
        setTimeout(function () {
            if (self.playing) {
                if (document.hasFocus()) {
                    t();
                } else {
                    self.gameOver();
                }
            }
        }, 1000)
    };
    t();
}
```

The function calls itself each second and checks if the tab has lost focus. This is what probably happened in your case.

#### But I want to take a break so that I don't see unicorns everywhere!

Enter this in your console as a "temporary" solution:

```
Runner.instance_.focusCheck = function(){if(!this.nfc){var n=this,t=function(){setTimeout(function(){n.playing&&(document.hasFocus()?t():n.stop())},1e3)};t()}}
```

This changes `n.gameOver()` to `n.stop()`.

---

#### New way

Because Yaakov has made this not work by using `const focusCheck = function(){}` which made the function private here's another hacky way to do this (*warning: this overrides the native `document.hasFocus()` function!*):

```
var original = Document.prototype.hasFocus;
Document.prototype.hasFocus = function(test) {
    return test ? original.apply(this, arguments) : true;
}
setInterval(() => {
    if (Runner.instance_.playing && !document.hasFocus(true)) Runner.instance_.stop();
}, 1000);
```

However, because the time will still be recorded and thanks to the newest anti-cheating heuristics, you might get banned from the leaderboard if you pause the game for too long.

Comment: Your hack doesn't work anymore. Oh well.